# Send whole form in Pdf format when press submit button

Tags: objective-c

I am making an iphone application in which i struck at one part which is..when the user press submit button i want to send the whole form in pdf to the specific email .
Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: This question is far too vague and broad. Please narrow down to a specific question and clarify your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)takeScreenShot
{
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
else
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIImageView *newImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[self createPDFfromUIView:newImage saveToDocumentsWithFileName:@"SecondScreen1.pdf"];
}


-(void)createPDFfromUIView:(UIImageView*)aView saveToDocumentsWithFileName:(NSString*)aFilename
{
// Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array
NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
// Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.view.bounds, nil);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

// draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData
[aView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

// remove PDF rendering context
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

// Retrieves the document directories from the iOS device
NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,      NSUserDomainMask,YES);

NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFilename];

// instructs the mutable data object to write its context to a file on disk
[pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"documentDirectoryFileName: %@",documentDirectoryFilename);
}
```

It would be work.